# Powershell: Calculated Property not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file in which i need to add a new column. I do that with import-csv and then adding a property to the objects before writing it back to csv with export-csv.

Somehow its not working as expected. I took all real functionality out and reduced it to the following snipped:

```
$findReplaceList = Import-Csv -Path $mappingListPath -Delimiter ';'

Import-Csv $sourceFile.FullName | 
            Select-Object *, @{Name = 'column3'; Expression = 
                { $newKey = $_."Issue key" ; $newKey } 
            } | 
            Export-Csv $outputFullFileName -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

please note that in this code the real calculation of the Expression is replaced with something very simple.

here, with

```
$newKey = $_."Issue key"
```

I just try to take the value in column "issue key" and use that for the newly added column.

Somehow the $newKey is always NULL - although $_."Issue key" is not?

What am i doing wrong?
The real code for $newKey will be:

```
{$newKey = $_.$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[0]; (@($findReplaceList).where( { $_.$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[0] -eq $newKey })).$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[3] }
```

The mapping File (reference by $mappingListPath) is a simple csv like that:

[image of a simple sample mapping table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODXPX.png)

Comment: Can you post your real expression? As I'm reading this `$_."Issue key"` should be all you need.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, I used the $newKey here just as a placeholder. Ofc, for the simple statement above it would not be needed. The real expression would be:
{$newKey = $_.$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[0]; (@($findReplaceList).where( { $_.$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[0] -eq $newKey })).$FieldsToSelectFromTargetFilesIntoMappingFile[3] }

Comment: Can you update your question with that? For the record, I tested the `Select-Object` portion with my own data, and get the expected result: `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Bender'; 'Cool Beans' = 'Rad' } |select-object *, @{ Name = 'Status'; Expression = { $status = "$($_.Name) is $($_.'Cool Beans')"; $status } }`

Comment: @user7376515 Please update the post with _reproducible_ code. At first glance it looks like you could benefit from replacing `$findReplaceList` with a hashtable or dictionary, but hard to give good advice without knowing/seeing actual problematic code

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added the missing pieces.. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Thanks to all the comments and the working code sample from @Bender the greatest i was able to identify the issue with my code: The csv mapping file has ';' as delimiters... With the code i wrote the different "columns" in the csv where not identified as such, but each line was just written into one single property.

By changing

```
Import-Csv $sourceFile.FullName |
```

to

```
Import-Csv $sourceFile.FullName -delimiter ';' |
```

the problem was solved.